# SQL Server - Optimize this query with million records

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2000

I have table with 2 million records for now, it will increase by 0.05 million records per day, so I want optimize this query

```
Select * from Forex where Id in 
(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol having Symbol in 
(Select Distinct Symbol from Forex) )
```

I have create NONCLUSTERED INDEX  so the time taken for this query is 673milliseconds. I have modified the query to

```
Select * from Forex where Id in 
(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol having  Symbol in 
('AUDCAD','AUDCHF','AUDJPY','AUDNZD','AUDUSD','CADCHF','CHFJPY', 
'EURAUD','EURCAD','EURCHF','EURGBP','EURJPY','EURNOK','EURNZD', 
'EURUSD','GBPCAD','GBPCHF','GBPJPY','GBPUSD','NZDJPY','NZDUSD', 
'USDCAD','USDCHF','USDJPY','USDNOK','USDSEK'))
```

Now the time taken is 391milliseconds

Is it possible to make less than 100milliseconds? Or Some one help to optimize this query

Comment: Why wouldn't: `Select * from Forex where Id in (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol)` Work for you?

Comment: `FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol having Symbol in (Select Distinct Symbol from Forex) )` seems pointless. Why is that `IN` clause there? Do you have a separate table with the distinct symbols that you can use?

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Well that rules out `ROW_NUMBER`, `CROSS APPLY` and recursive CTEs all of which could have helped.

Comment: Select * from Forex where Id in (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol) made it to 313 milliseconds

Comment: @MartinSmith can you be more specific, I could not get it

Comment: The comment was just indicating that versions that have been released in the last decade have greater possibilities for getting a more appropriate plan through rewriting the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only have 26 symbols and a million rows 26 index seeks may be better (assumes an index on `Symbol ASC, Id DESC`)

```
DECLARE @Id     INT,
        @Symbol VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @Results TABLE(
  Id     INT,
  Symbol VARCHAR(10))

SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id,
             @Symbol = Symbol
FROM   Forex
ORDER  BY Symbol ASC,
          Id DESC

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT = 1
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @Results
      VALUES      (@Id,
                   @Symbol)

      SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id,
                   @Symbol = Symbol
      FROM   Forex
      WHERE  Symbol > @Symbol
      ORDER  BY Symbol ASC,
                Id DESC
  END

SELECT *
FROM   @Results
```

Comment: @SatishBejgum - Did you create the index on `Symbol ASC, Id DESC`?

Comment: I have created CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Forex_29_85575343__K2_K1] ON [dbo].[Forex] 
(
 [Symbol] ASC,
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @SatishBejgum - It needs to be `Id  DESC` not `Id  ASC`. Also are you sure you are on SQL Server 2000? That `dta` prefix looks like database tuning advisor which wasn't released until 2005 (except if the index tuning wizard used the same prefix)

Comment: After changing the [Id] ASC to [Id] DESC the time taken is 15ms

Comment: a small doubt: will this help even with newly created records?

Comment: @SatishBejgum - Yes. If new symbols are added the results will still be correct. It will only be optimum if the number of symbols is very small compared to overall number of rows though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of the `HAVING` clause:

```
Select * from Forex where Id in 
(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex GROUP BY Symbol)
```

you could also try this version:

```
SELECT * FROM Forex F
WHERE Id =
(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex WHERE Symbol = F.Symbol)
```

though I wouldn't expect it to be dramatically different.

Some broad strokes (some may work, some may not):

1. Make sure you have indexes on `Id` and `Symbol, Id DESC`.  If the index on `Id` can be CLUSTERED it would help as well.
2. Don't return all columns if you don't need to.
3. De-normalize the table by moving `Symbol` to another, smaller table
4. Add memory
5. Add CPU
6. Use faster hard drives

Comment: SELECT * FROM Forex F
    WHERE Id =
    (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Forex WHERE Symbol = F.Symbol)
This took 328milliseconds